# Add blank line between paragraphs in Crystal Reports Formula Field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

In my report, I have a parameter that I use to pass some configurable text stored in a database to the report.  This text then gets displayed on the report.

I want that text to include some basic formatting (i.e. bold, italics, centering, etc.).  To accomplish this, I place the parameter on the report and format it as `HTML`.  The text then includes HTML tags that accomplish the formatting.

This all works until I want to include a blank line between paragraphs (i.e. "double spacing").  In HTML I would add multiple `<br/>` tags.  However, Crystal Report only interprets that as "single spacing".

If I switch the display mode from `HTML` to `none`, and replace `<br/><br/>` with `chr(13)+chr(13)` (plus a few changes involving a formula field -- it won't work with the `chr(13)` just embedded in the incoming text), I do get my "double spacing" between paragraphs.  However, I then lose the ability to include any kind of text formatting within the paragraph.

Is there a way to force a "double space" between paragraphs dynamically in Crystal Reports and still retain the ability to dynamically format portions of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to accomplish this by replacing the use of `<br/>` with:

```html
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Kind of a pain, but it works.

Comment: Crystal Reports doesn't support the self-closing version of the `<br>` tag.  Here's a good [resource](https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1217084) on which tags are supported if you ever need them.

Answer (score 1):

With html interpretation:

```
<br> gives a new line break (no empty line)
<br><br> would give you a single empty line.
<br><br><br> would give you 2 empty lines.
```

You probably need the `<br><br><br>` version to get your desired effect.